# Name of the book with a non controversial set of known FLT things BEFORE FLT was proven with modular forms?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Prior to the modern proof of FLT (Fermat's Last Theorem) there was a book that references the known facts about FLT.

Where $x^p+y^p=z^p$ is the variable choice

The equations I am referring to say something like

x=$(w^p-m^p+n^p)/2$

y=$(w^p+m^p-n^p)/2$

z=$(w^p+m^p+n^p)/2$ then it had a special case like w^p being replaced with p^(p-1) $w^p$

Does anyone recognize these equations?

It may have used a,b,c instead of w,m,n but I use w,m,n because I already had that part before I saw the book and named them differently.

Does anyone know the source for this equation?

I can prove p divides 2xy as a general case and if the $n^p$ and $m^p$ do not have this p^(p-1) term in a valid proof then that is probably what Fermat used.

Thanks for your help.

Specific question is "do you know the source of these equations and where I can find them".

The equation referenced is not mine and is not controversial.  I may have mis remembered it but an equation essentially identical existed in a book of known material prior to FLT being proven via modular forms.

My belief that I can prove p divides 2xy is not what this question is about.

EDIT:
It appears the equations I am referring to were found by Barlow and Abel.  It also appears they only apply when p doesn't divide xyz or when p divides z but p divides xy so these may not be useful.

Comment: I don't think so.  I think it had a section what is known that just listed the known attributes.

Comment: Correction lecture 4 shows the equations come from Barlow and Abel.  I am looking  it seems that the equations may only apply in the case when p does not divide xy but it does.